# Where set timeout with post request using request package in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, timeout

I am making a post request using **request** package. how can I set timeout 500 ms while requesting.

```
var request = require('request');

request({
      url: 'myUrl',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authToken': 'myToken'
      },
      timeout: 500,
      json: infoObj
    })
      .on('response', function(response) {
        console.log('request response=============',response.statusCode)

      })
      .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('error===',err);
      });
```

when tried using timeout: 500, above example got error

> { Error: ETIMEDOUT
>       at Timeout._onTimeout (F:\gomean\globeone\node_modules\request\request.js:796:17)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:198:5) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', connect: true }

Comment: Can you tell us what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [`request({ ..., timeout: <milliseconds> })`](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback)

Comment: updated question that i tried

Comment: Your error looks like what you get when you get an unhandled timeout error.  I don't see any error handler in your code that would catch errors, including the timeout error.

Comment: node engine version?

Comment: node version "v6.2.1"

Comment: catching error by using `.on('error'` @jfriend00

Comment: That's one way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a callback to catch the error. From [the documentation](https://github.com/request/request#timeouts):

> You can detect timeout errors by checking err.code for an 'ETIMEDOUT' value. Further, you can detect whether the timeout was a connection timeout by checking if the err.connect property is set to true.

And an example:

```
request.get('http://10.255.255.1', {timeout: 1500}, function(err) {
    console.log(err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT');
    // Set to `true` if the timeout was a connection timeout, `false` or
    // `undefined` otherwise.
    console.log(err.connect === true);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Request Doc: 
**timeout** - Integer containing the number of milliseconds to wait for a server to send response headers (and start the response body) before aborting the request.

```
var request = require('request');

request({
      url: 'myUrl',
      method: 'POST',

      timeout: 500,

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authToken': 'myToken'
      },
      json: infoObj
    })
      .on('response', function(response) {
        console.log('request response=============',response.statusCode)

      })
```

Comment: I tried previously and got error . see updated question

Comment: try this package request-enhanced..............https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-enhanced